# Selenium Testrail integration

Tags: selenium, testrail

I am new to TestRail tool and wanted to integrate all my Selenium automation test cases with TestRail. I have 100+ test cases in excel sheet and running using Selenium Webdriver + Java + TestNg.

If I run any of test cases from Selenium project that result should get reflected in TestRail report. Looking around on the internet I found this URL: 
http://docs.gurock.com/testrail-api2/bindings-java.

But it doesn't tell how to use in my Selenium project.  Basically I wanted to know how to use this and where to keep this code. And also if I get detailed example(from TestRail side as well as Selenium Java code) with code would be more helpful to understand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31344490/integrate-selenium-test-results-with-testrail-4-0

Answer (score 0):

You can follow API docs from Testrail:

http://docs.gurock.com/testrail-api2/start

and have to create Your own RESTful service that will lean against Testrail API's.

I've created connection to Testrail with their docs, with additon of JSON (class) models for each of this actions.

For eg. fetching testcases

request:

```
GET index.php?/api/v2/get_test/:test_id
response:
```

response:

```
{
    "assignedto_id": 1,
    "case_id": 1,
    "custom_expected": "..",
    "custom_preconds": "..",
    "custom_steps_separated": [
        {
            "content": "Step 1",
            "expected": "Expected Result 1"
        },
        {
            "content": "Step 2",
            "expected": "Expected Result 2"
        }
    ],
    "estimate": "1m 5s",
    "estimate_forecast": null,
    "id": 100,
    "priority_id": 2,
    "run_id": 1,
    "status_id": 5,
    "title": "Verify line spacing on multi-page document",
    "type_id": 4
}
```

json model:

```
public class Test {
    private static final String CUSTOM_FIELD_KEY_PREFIX = "custom_";
    private int id;
    private int caseId;
    private Integer assignedtoId;
    private String title;
    private int statusId;
    private int typeId;
    private int priorityId;
    private Integer milestoneId;
    private Integer runId;
    private String refs;
    private String estimate;
    private String estimateForecast;
    private Map<String, Object> customFields;

    public Map<String, Object> getCustomFields() {
        return customFields;
    }
```

But probably the easiest way is to directly send request and parse response and create a small service around it.

Answer (score 0):

Since Selenium doesn't have a  way to send API requests.you need to use an Rest API cleint , so I used Rest-Assured. If you are using TestNG, in AfterMethod or AfterClass, you can use below code.

public void sendTestResultOfTestCase() {
String username = "myusername";
String password = "mypassword";
String runId = "29798"; //Remove the starting English letter R29798 , so it's 29798
String testCaseId = "1827330"; // Remove the starting English letter
String endpoint = "https://skynet.testrail.net/index.php?/api/v2/add_result_for_case/" + runId + "/" + testCaseId;
JSONObject requestParams = new JSONObject();

```
requestParams.put("status_id", "1");    // 1 means pass
requestParams.put("comment", "Hi, this test was passed via automation."); // optional comment.
requestParams.put("case_id", testCaseId);
requestParams.put("run_id", runId);
Response response = RestAssured.given().auth().preemptive().basic(username, password)
        .contentType("application/json")
        .body(requestParams.toString())
        .when()
        .post(endpoint);
System.out.println(response.getBody().asString());
```

}

1 means pass and two means blocked, 4 means retest and 5 means fail.